# Convert DateTime.Now to array

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert the DateTime.Now method to a string array. I looked up on StackOverflow and found the following solution.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string dateTM = dateTime.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm");
string[] dT = dateTM.Select(str => str.ToString()).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(MainPath + @"Log\Client-side.txt", dT);
```

The problem is that it took me like 3 statement lines to declare it so I was wondering if there's any way to be shorter?
I know this is some basic coding but despite that I still couldn't find any clear answer on the internet.

Hope you can help me out!

Comment: While you of course can short every code into a single line it doesn´t make your code any better, in particular it will get only harder to understand. Your code is pretty straightforward and easy, why want to obfuscate it by any possible modification.

Comment: @HimBromBeere true, but I was still wondering if it could be any shorter and at the same time quite readable.

Comment: Do you really find `File.WriteAllLines(MainPath + ..., DateTime.Now.ToString(...).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()` any better?

Comment: Why do you even want to write every charachter into a seperate line in the first place? Is it me, or did you overlook `File.WriteAllText`

Comment: @Everyone my expected results are: as you can see I use the method WriteAllLines in the class File. This one only accept a string array as arguments. So maybe instead of using the .WriteAllLines method we could use something else?

Comment: @Filburt srry. didn't knew this existed

Comment: @CSharpie hmm. Maybe another method could be better? Maybe streamwriter

Comment: I retracted my close votes - you should rewrite your question to reflect your actual problem which isn't dissecting a date and time string into an array but writing a single line into a text file.

Comment: You need to re-phrase your question. The way it's currently written, it seems like you want to shorten the code from 4 lines to one line. But from the comments it seems like you really just wanted to know how to write the date as a single line (i.e. `WriteAllText`). Also, just FYI, you *could* just create an array with a single element (your date.ToString()) and then use `WriteAllLines` as you're currently doing: `string[] dT = {dateTM};`

Answer (score 0):

You can condense this to something like;

```
string[] segments = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm").Split(' ');
```

**EDIT**

Updated to add that if you want all characters in a string array, then you can reference a string like;

```
string test = "Hello world";
char character = test[2];   // contains 'l'
```

Strings are already effective character arrays and can be referenced as such.

This could be modify your existing code to;

```
string segments = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMM,yyyyHH:mm");
File.WriteAllLines(MainPath + @"Log\Client-side.txt", segments.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: From OPs code he wants every single character in the array, not just the groups. Don´t ask me *why*.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Is there any other way of writing a file with it contents? Instead of the .WriteAllLines method?

Comment: Try WriteAllText

Comment: Just some nitpicking: `ToCharArray()` is not needed, since string allready is `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write a TimeStamp into a file then just use `File.WriteAllText`

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string dateTM = dateTime.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm");
File.WriteAllText(MainPath + @"Log\Client-side.txt", dateTM);
```

To retrieve, there is `File.ReadAllText`

Also you can use `File.WriteAllLines` like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

List<string> lines = new List<string>();
lines.Add(dateTM);
lines.Add("Hello World!");

File.WriteAllLines(MainPath + @"Log\Client-side.txt", lines);
```